# InnerText JavaScript Losing the beginning newline?

Tags: javascript

I have a modal in HTML, and I am trying to append some text to its `InnerText` attribute, but it seems that one of the newlines gets ignored. For example, I want it to be this:

```
class Student{

}
class AG{

}
```

But instead, it is:

```
class Student{ }
class AG{

}
```

I tried adding more newlines, and removing some extra ones that could have been a problem, but nothing happened. I tried using the `InnterHTML` attribute, but that didn't solve it either.

```js
var generatedCode = "";
var classNameCode = {};

document.getElementById("create-box").addEventListener("click", function() {
  let box = document.createElement("div");
  box.classList.add("box");
  let title = document.createElement("h2");
  title.innerHTML = "Class";
  box.appendChild(title);
  let classTitle = document.createElement('input');
  classTitle.classList.add('class-name-form');
  let classTitleBtn = document.createElement('button');
  classTitleBtn.innerText = "Set Class Name";
  classTitle.classList.add('class-name-btn');
  box.appendChild(classTitle);
  box.appendChild(classTitleBtn);
  document.getElementById("box-container").appendChild(box);
  let createSubclassButton = document.createElement("button");
  createSubclassButton.innerHTML = "Add Method";
  box.appendChild(createSubclassButton);

  // Enable resizing and dragging
  box.addEventListener("mousedown", startDrag);
  box.addEventListener("mousemove", drag);
  box.addEventListener("mouseup", endDrag);
  box.addEventListener("mouseleave", endDrag);

  let offset = [0, 0];
  let isDown = false;

  function startDrag(e) {
    isDown = true;
    offset = [
      this.offsetLeft - e.clientX,
      this.offsetTop - e.clientY
    ];
  }

  function drag(e) {
    if (!isDown) return;
    e.preventDefault();
    this.style.left = (e.clientX + offset[0]) + 'px';
    this.style.top = (e.clientY + offset[1]) + 'px';
  }

  function endDrag(e) {
    isDown = false;
  }

  createSubclassButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
    let subBox = document.createElement("div");
    subBox.classList.add("subbox");
    let subTitle = document.createElement("h2");
    subTitle.innerText = "New Method";
    subBox.append(subTitle);
    document.getElementById("box-container").appendChild(subBox);
    subBox.style.left = box.offsetLeft + box.offsetWidth + 10 + 'px';
    subBox.style.top = box.offsetTop + 'px';

    // Enable resizing and dragging for the subbox
    subBox.addEventListener("mousedown", startDrag);
    subBox.addEventListener("mousemove", drag);
    subBox.addEventListener("mouseup", endDrag);
    subBox.addEventListener("mouseleave", endDrag);
  });

  classTitleBtn.addEventListener("click", function() {
    console.log(classTitle.value);
    // generatedCode = `class ${classTitle.value} {\n\t`
    classNameCode[classTitle.value] = `\nclass ${classTitle.value} {\n`
  });
});





// MODAL FOR CODE GENERATION
var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");


var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

var modalContent = document.querySelector('.modal-content');


btn.onclick = function() {
  modalContent.innerText = "";
  console.log(classNameCode);
  for (var key in classNameCode) {
    var codeToAppend = `${classNameCode[key]} \n}`;
    console.log(codeToAppend);
    modalContent.innerText += codeToAppend;
  }
  modal.style.display = "block";
}


window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  background-size: 40px 40px;
  background-image: radial-gradient(circle, #000000 1px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 1px);
  background-color: darkgray;
}

#create-box {
  padding: 10px 20px;
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: none;
  color: white;
}

#create-box:hover {
  background-color: #5dc861;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#create-box:active {
  cursor: pointer
}

.box {
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
  border-radius: 5px;
  resize: both;
  overflow: auto;
  z-index: 1;
}

.box h2 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px;
}

.subbox {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  border-radius: 5px;
}


/* The Modal (background) */

.modal {
  display: none;
  /* Hidden by default */
  position: fixed;
  /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 1;
  /* Sit on top */
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  /* Full width */
  height: 100%;
  /* Full height */
  overflow: auto;
  /* Enable scroll if needed */
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  /* Black w/ opacity */
}


/* Modal Content/Box */

.modal-content {
  background-color: #fefefe;
  margin: 15% auto;
  /* 15% from the top and centered */
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #888;
  width: 80%;
  /* Could be more or less, depending on screen size */
}


/* The Close Button */

.close {
  color: #aaa;
  float: right;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#myBtn {
  padding: 10px 20px;
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: none;
  color: white;
}

#myBtn:hover {
  background-color: #5dc861;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#myBtn:active {
  cursor: pointer
}

#buttons {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="buttons">
  <button id="create-box">Create Class</button>
  <button id="myBtn">View Code (C++)</button>
</div>
<div id="box-container"></div>
<div id="myModal" class="modal">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <p></p>
  </div>

</div>
<script src="main.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Solutions

Your `btn.onclick` handler should be modified.
Any of the following should work:

1. Avoid reading `innerText` while the modal is hidden by collecting your code fragments in a variable and only after the loop set the `innerText`:

   ```js
   console.log(classNameCode);
   let code = '';
   for(var key in classNameCode){
       var codeToAppend = `${classNameCode[key]} \n}`;
       console.log(codeToAppend);
       code += codeToAppend;
   }
   modalContent.innerText = code; // avoid reading innerText when modal is hidden
   modal.style.display = "block";
   ```
2. Avoid surprising `innerText` read behavior for hidden elements by first making it visible. You can do so by moving `modal.style.display = "block";` to the start of the `btn.onclick` handler function:

   ```js
   modal.style.display = "block";
   modalContent.innerText = "";
   console.log(classNameCode);
   for(var key in classNameCode){
       var codeToAppend = `${classNameCode[key]} \n}`;
       console.log(codeToAppend);
       modalContent.innerText += codeToAppend;
   }
   ```

### Reason

While writing a value containing a line break to `innerText` always creates `<br>` elements, reading it from a *hidden* element behaves differently: it ignores the descendant `<br>` elements.

In your `btn.onclick` handler, you wrote `.innerText += ...` which means reading the current value and the writing in the next step.

In the second iteration of the loop, you are reading the existing `innerText` which returns the text *without the line break from the first iteration* (although there is a `<br>` in the DOM). You then write the concatenation of this and the the second `codeToAppend` which terminally removes the line break from the first iteration from the modal's contents.

### Research

I have copied your code into local files and reduced the example until I found the actual cause:

Having *only* the style `.modal { display: none; }` active, the bad behavior can be observed. Without that style, the new lines are added as desired.

So I've found that the culprit is `display: none` which seems to have an effect on how `innerText` is working.

Looking at the [HTML specification](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#the-innertext-idl-attribute) of `innerText` seems to confirms this, as it mentions special handling for the case where the element is not being rendered.

In particular, it states:

> If this is not being rendered or if the user agent is a non-CSS user agent, then return this's [descendant text content](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-descendant-text-content).

The `descendant text content` is defined as:

> The descendant text content of a node node is the concatenation of the data of all the Text node descendants of node, in tree order.

Clearly, this does not include `<br>` elements and that's why your `innerText` does not contain the line breaks as you desire.

The `innerText` specification mentions special handling for `<br>` only in the case, the element is being rendered. In particular, it states that for each rendered descendant node, the [rendered text collection steps](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#rendered-text-collection-steps) are being executed and those contain:

> If node is a `br` element, then append a string containing a single U+000A LF code point to items.

Answer (score 1):

By default, new lines in HTML are not interpreted as new lines to render on screen. You can either:

- Add `white-space: pre;` property to `.modal-content`. This element will now respect carriage returns.
- Use `innerHTML` and instead of appending carriage returns (`\n`) append a `<br/>` tag.

You also probably want to do `\r\n` instead of just `\n` or it may not work properly on windows browsers.

Comment: Sorry fixed the error in my first bullet

Comment: Notice that depending on how the program might develop, additional escaping might be needed. I would replace at least `<` by `&lt;`, `&` by `&amp;` and `>` by `&gt;` to be safe. Also see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML#replacing_the_contents_of_an_element. In particular, if the content comes from other users, writing `innerHTML` without care might introduce a security vulnerability. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML#security_considerations also recommends using `innerText`.